# Mockbean annotation behaves randomly on Jenkins

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jenkins

So in my spring tests I use @Mockbean for several beans.

Locally it works fine.

But when running on Jenkins the following strange behaviour happens:

The mocked version of the bean injected correctly to everywhere except one class.

In that class roughly 80percent of the time the real bean is injected instead of the mocked one. For the other 20percent of the time the mocked one is injected and works fine.

What could be the cause?

The test is run on jenkins with mvn clean test.
Jenkins and my local env has the same jdk and the same mvn.

What should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few things to consider

1. If two tests load the same `@Configuration` (or xml) and don't use `@MockBean` they will share a single `ApplicationContext` instance (assuming they are run one after the other)
2. Any test that declares a `MockBean` will NOT share the `ApplicationContext` with other tests. Instead it will destroy the current `ApplicationContext` and create a new one. The next test will also destroy the current `ApplicationContext` (since it can't be shared) and create a new one.
3. If you use `@MockBean` in your test suite then the order in which your run your tests can affect the behaviour. If you run the `@MockBean` test in the middle of 2 "sharing" tests it might cause 3 `ApplicationContext` to be created. If you ran the `@MockBean` test after the 2 "sharing" tests only 2 `ApplicationContext` are created.
4. Static variables are shared between all of your tests (regardless of `@MockBean`). If you call `SomeService.setX(...)` in one test it may "bleed" into another test (via `SomeService.getX()`). This can cause problems where the order you execute your tests matters (eg running `TestA` before `TestB` passes but running `TestA` after `TestB` fails). In my opinion static variables should be immutable, if you need to mutate a static variable you should instead inject a service instance and mutate that instead (much easier to mock/test).
5. If you want to track down cases where state from one test is "bleeding" into another you might want to do some assertions in `@BeforeTest` of the failing test.
6. I have personally been stung a few times by `@MockBean` and I now refuse to use it. I instead have a single test `@Configuration` which is shared between all of my tests for "integration" testing (I also use `@RunWith(MockitoExtension.class)` for unit testing)